# How to stream data from kafka avro console to HDFS using kafka-connect-hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to run kafka-connect-hdfs without any success.

I have added the following line to .bash_profile and ran 'source ~/.bash_profile'

```
export LOG_DIR=~/logs
```

The quickstart-hdfs.properties configuration file is

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
hdfs.url=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx # placeholder
flush.size=3

hadoop.conf.dir = /etc/hadoop/conf/
logs.dir = ~/logs
topics.dir = ~/topics
topics=test_hdfs
```

I am following the quickstart instructions outlined in
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html

The contents of the connector-avro-stanalone.properties file are:

```
bootstrap.servers=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:yyyy # This is the placeholder for the Kafka broker url with the appropriate port
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

I have the quickstart-hdfs.properties and connector-avro-stanalone.properties in my home directory and I run:

```
confluent load hdfs-sink -d quickstart-hdfs.properties
```

I am not sure how I am accessing the information in the connector-avro-stanalone.properties file in my home directory.

When I run:  'confluent log connect', I get the following error:

```
[2018-04-26 17:36:00,217] INFO Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector: (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask:90)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:56)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:213)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:101)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:82)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:267)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:163)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:51)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> This is the hdfs_url in quickstart-hdfs.properties file without the port
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getUnique(FileSystem.java:2691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.newInstance(FileSystem.java:420)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage.<init>(HdfsStorage.java:56)
        ... 17 more
[2018-04-26 17:36:00,217] INFO Shutting down HdfsSinkConnector. (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask:91)
```

Any help to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

You need `hdfs.url=hdfs://xxx.yyy.zzz.abc` along with the namenode port

Also, you'll want to remove the spaces around the equals signs in the properties files

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for your reply. In the configuration file, the hdfs.url already has the url, along with the appropriate port, from the value of the property in /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml the name of which is dfs.namenode.https-address. I have two hdfs-site.xml files one at /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml and the other at /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hdfs-site.xml, though these files are identical. Just removing the spaces from the quickstart-hdfs.properties does not change anything. Also, I use a quickstart-hdfs.properties in my home directory.

Comment: It's not the HTTPS address that you need. It's the Namenode RPC address. Also `~/logs` and `~/topics` must be absolute paths on HDFS

Comment: Hi cricket_007, I made the changes you suggested, but the problem still persists. Thanks

Comment: You'll want to make sure `plugin.path=/usr/share/java/` , which is the directory containing `kafka-connect-hdfs` (assuming you are running Confluent 4.x)

Comment: Hi cricket_007, I fixed the hdfs.url and ensured that plugin.path is correct. I am know getting a different error:

Comment: The new error is: [2018-05-07 18:25:00,634] INFO Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector: (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask:90)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operat
ion category READ is not supported in state standby

Comment: That's not a Kafka problem. Your HDFS is degraded. Your active namenode is now the standby

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: That error is past your initial `No FileSystem for scheme`, so if you want, you can accept this answer and open a new one for figuring out your HDFS issues

Comment: Hi cricket_007, now I do not get an error message but when I run hadoop fs -ls /topics, I get an empty /topics/+tmp file. Thanks, Ambarish.